# SharePoint People Picker not picking users from inside AD Group

Tags: sharepoint-server, people-picker, ad

I have an AD Group inside a SharePoint Group, and a Person or Group field that's choosing from the SharePoint Group. When I look for a person that's in the mentioned AD GRoup, the person is not being found. I have run multiple Full Syncs and IIS Resets, and made sure the User PRofile is also syncing Groups and pulling from the right containers, but nothing fixed this. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what version of SharePoint you're using. For SP 2013, I would start with AD to see if the user/group is still active. Then, in Central Admin, I would search user profile (UPS application) to see if the profile already exists or not. Also, in your profile sync, do you have any filter that prevent that group from transferring from AD to SharePoint?

Comment: SP 2013 on premise, and I did make sure it's importing groups also...

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, the result is the same.

If you choose from **SharePoint group** which includes a AD group, it will only show the AD group instead of individual users in AD group.

As a workaround, you need to choose from **All users**, or add users existing in the AD group to the SharePoint group individually.

[image][image]

Comment: Really there's no way of putting an AD group into the SharePoint group to reduce duplicating/maintenance if a person leaves or is added?

Comment: Yes, if you put the AD group into SharePoint group, it is not possible to achieve this. I suggest you grant permission to the AD group directly, and then choose from the AD group,  so that you can confirm who left or was added

Comment: @Julie_MSFT is this still not possible? The whole point of AD groups is that you don't need to manually fix up SharePoint groups, since it's already been done in AD. Why does it not read the AD group members and be done??